# php laravel Model database - Unique violation Error

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

I'm trying to add a new proverb to my table proverbe that already have many proverb but i have error :

> SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "proverbes_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(32)
>   already exists. (SQL: insert into "proverbes" ("proverbe",
>   "signification", "theme", "pays", "ethnie", "updated_at",
>   "created_at") values (La langue qui parle de la femme n'est pas
>   tordue, Qui parle du faible parle librement., Liberte, Gabon,
>   Massango, 2017-06-11 18:52:46, 2017-06-11 18:52:46))

Answer (score 1):

you don't have a proverbes_pkey in your insert, and most likely didn't make it an auto-incrementing value in the DB, so it gets a default value, which happens to already exist elsewhere in the table, causing your error.

Comment: Use autoincrementing on primary key column and update the sequence for it's numeration

Comment: autoincrement primary key.